# The right way to write this Stateless Widget

Tags: flutter

I have the following stateless widget that shows an SVG image:

```dart
class MessageReactionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget icon;
  final double size;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double _ratio = 0.75;

  MessageReactionWidget(String reaction, {Key key, this.size = 40.0, this.backgroundColor = Colors.white})
      : super(key: key) {
    switch (reaction) {
      case 'like':
      case 'funny':
        icon = SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/smile.svg', height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
        break;
      case 'love':
        icon = SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/heart.svg', height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
        break;
      case 'wow':
        icon = SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/clap.svg', height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
        break;
      case 'thumbsdown':
        icon = SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/thumbsdown.svg',
            height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
        break;
      case 'sad':
        icon = SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/sad.svg', height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
        break;
      default:
        icon =
            SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/thumbsup.svg', height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: icon,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: size,
        width: size,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: backgroundColor,
        ));
  }
}
```

This works fine, but Flutter gives a warning because `icon` is not `final`:

> This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as
> '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final:
> MessageReactionWidget.icon

The `icon` will not change because it is set in the constructor, but it can't be marked final because it is not set immediately.  What is the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You should change it from a StatlessWidget to a StatefullWidget.  Update the icon value from inside a setState bloc, so the UI is updated correctly.

ex

```
setState(() {
  icon = someWidget;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a field that you **initialized** later in the code add `late` before that field like this.

```
late Widget icon
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pass icon as an argument:

```
class MessageReactionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget icon;
  final double size;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double _ratio = 0.75;

  MessageReactionWidget({Key key, required this.icon, this.size = 40.0, this.backgroundColor = Colors.white})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: icon,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: size,
        width: size,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: backgroundColor,
        ));
  }
}
```

and in its parent widget, define a method that you call in its builder:

```
    Icon getIcon(String reaction){
    switch (reaction) {
          case 'like':
          case 'funny':
            return SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/smile.svg', height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
          case 'love':
            return SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/heart.svg', height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
          case 'wow':
            return SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/clap.svg', height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
          case 'thumbsdown':
            return SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/thumbsdown.svg',
                height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
          case 'sad':
            return SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/sad.svg', height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
          default:
            return
                SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/icons/thumbsup.svg', height: size * _ratio, color: Styles.colorSteadyState);
        }
    }
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MessageReactionWidget(icon: getIcon(reaction), size: size, backgroundColor: backgroundColor);
}
```